# Plotting pixels on a map image

Tags: point

I've got a list of some hundreds of latitude/longitude pairs close to each other (within a country). I want to create an image with a map, and circles overlaid around these points. Basically, what I need is:

- an image of a map
- a way of translating latitude/longitude pairs to pixels

Where can I obtain a fitting map (e.g. roadmap or satellite map) with the parameters needed to plot the points? I suppose there is some FOSS tool that does most of this already?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option would be to download [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/)

You should then plot your points using the 'Add Delimited Text layer' if your data is in that format.

Finally, you can use the data from either [Shaded Relief](http://www.shadedrelief.com/), or [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) as the background

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to use QGIS from the command-line, so that I can use it to generate the image in another script?

Comment: @Andreas I am not much of an expert on scripting QGIS, so I really don't know whether you can do so or not.

Comment: you may be looking for GDAL Rasterizer. there is a command line app gdal_rasterize http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html and OGR do support csv formats or you can convert between diffrent OGR formats like csv to shape using another commandline tool available in the same package ogr2ogr http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html